# Proguard 7.3.2 not able to find classes when using openjdk-11

Tags: java, ant, proguard, java-11

I am using openjdk-11 and proguard version is 7.3.2 and while build one of the module i am getting many warnings as below:

```
[javac] Reading library jmod [/opt/jdk-11/jmods/java.base.jmod] (filtered)
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileStore]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtDirectoryStream]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtUtils]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileAttributeView$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystemProvider]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileAttributeView]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.ExplodedImage]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath$2]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.SystemImage$2]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.ExplodedImage$PathNode]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystemProvider$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtDirectoryStream$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileAttributes]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.SystemImage]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystemProvider$JrtFsLoader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileAttributeView$AttrID]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jrtfs.SystemImage$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageBufferCache$BufferReference]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageBufferCache$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageStrings]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$Resource]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReaderFactory$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.NativeImageBuffer]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$SharedImageReader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.StringSharingDecompressorFactory]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.CompressIndexes]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.CompressedResourceHeader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.SignatureParser$ParseResult]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ResourceDecompressor]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ResourceDecompressorFactory]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.StringSharingDecompressor]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.SignatureParser]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ZipDecompressorFactory]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ZipDecompressor]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ResourceDecompressorRepository]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.ResourceDecompressor$StringsProvider]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.decompressor.Decompressor]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageStringsReader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageBufferCache$2]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.BasicImageReader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$Directory]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$SharedImageReader$LocationVisitor]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.BasicImageReader$2]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.BasicImageReader$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageBufferCache]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageHeader]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageLocation]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReaderFactory]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$LinkNode]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.NativeImageBuffer$1]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageReader$Node]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: duplicate definition of library class [jdk.internal.jimage.ImageStream]
17:33:35     [javac] Note: there were 57 duplicate class definitions.
17:33:35     [javac]       (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass)
17:33:35     [javac] Initializing...
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JFrame
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
com.test.UtilPanel: find referenced class com.test.StringUtils
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'java.awt.Container getContentPane()' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'void pack()' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'java.awt.Dimension getPreferredSize()' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'void setLocation(int,int)' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'void setVisible(boolean)' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced method 'void setDefaultCloseOperation(int)' in program class com.test.UtilPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagLayout
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagLayout
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.BorderFactory
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.BorderFactory
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.BorderFactory
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
com.test.UtilPanel: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextField
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextField
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextField
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.Document
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.BorderFactory
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.Document
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextField
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class java.awt.GridBagConstraints
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
com.test.Utils: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JScrollPane
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.Document
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.Document
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.BadLocationException
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentListener
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.text.Document
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
com.test.Utils: : can't find referenced class javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent
```

Though i have added all the required JMODS in ant build file as below

option:1

```
<libraryjar file="/opt/jdk-11/jmods/java.base.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
            <libraryjar file="/opt/jdk-11/jmods/java.desktop.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
            <libraryjar file="/opt/jdk-11/jmods/java.management.jmod" jarfilter="!**.jar" filter="!module-info.class" />
```

Option 2:
Even tried adding

```
<libraryjar file="${libs.dir}/java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar" />
```

which has all the required file but still same error

Can anyone please assist on what can be the issue?

Comment: `.jmod` files are not `.jar` files. This `java-rt-jar-stubs-1.5.0.jar` file is not a standard artifact, so we can’t say anything about it…

Comment: Please provide the full proguard configuration.

Answer (score 0):

resolved the above issue by adding the ignore warnings in proguard definition

Comment: I was actually looking around on how to specify the libraryjar for new modular java and your question got me to my answer.